# Using conditional inside a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, asynchronous, nightwatch.js

I am new with javascript and nightwatch js.

I am trying to automate an online test which has between 4 and 5 questions maximum which are randomly generated.  Each question goes on a new page load so basically you answer a question, submit it and then get presented the next one.

The answers can be in different types, some of them are YES/NO buttons, some of them are multiple choice that you click, some of them are typing data into a text field which then you have to submit by pressing the Enter key on the keyboard.  Luckily the locators used for each one of these types of answers are always the same (not dynamically generated). For example.  Yes/No questions, the Yes answer will always be .answerYes or if it's a text field will always be #answerBox.

I need to go through the 4 or 5 questions and it doesn't matter if I answer them correctly.

I am thinking about using a for loop where I check if I get one of these elements I already identified and if so, I do the action and continue to the next page until the questionnaire is finished.

I have in mind something like the example below. I don't think this will work since javascript is asynchronous - which I don't fully understand yet.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 

    if (client.waitForElementVisible('.element1',1000)) {

        client.click('.element1');  //This would select first answer 
        client.click('nextButton'); //This would continue to the next question

    }
    else if (client.waitForElementVisible('.element2',1000)) {

        client.click('.element2');  //This would select first answer 
        client.click('nextButton'); //This would continue to the next question

    }
    else if (client.waitForElementVisible('.element3',1000)) {

        client.click('.element3');  //This would select first answer 
        client.click('nextButton'); //This would continue to the next question

    }
    else if (client.waitForElementVisible('.element4',1000)) {

        client.click('.element4');  //This would select first answer 
        client.click('nextButton'); //This would continue to the next question
    }
    else if (client.waitForElementVisible('.element5',1000)) { //element 5 would be the confirmation that test is over

        client.click('.element5'); //this would click the OK button when notified test is done
        leaveTheLoop(); //Not sure what would be the command to leave the loop  
    }
}
```

I was looking also at the Switch Statement for javascript but I don't think I can write in the expression something that would validate if any of the elements I am expecting will be present all under one expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep chaining 
`.waitForElementVisible(selector,timeout,abortOnFailure,callback)` to check whether elements are visible.

By setting `abortOnFailure` to `false` so the whole test won't fail, and you can continue for element2,3,4,5 even element1 is not visible.

Here is the code:

```
test(client){
     client.waitForElementVisible('.element1',1000,false,function(){
           client.click('.element1');  //This would select the first answer 
                 .click('nextButton'); 
            })
           .waitForElementVisible('.element2',1000,false,function(){
           client.click('.element2');  //This would select the second answer 
                 .click('nextButton');
           })                                     
           .waitForElementVisible('.element3',1000,false,function(){
            client.click('.element3');  //This would select the third answer 
                  .click('nextButton');
           })                                
           .waitForElementVisible('.element4',1000,false,function(){
           client.click('.element4');  //This would select the forth answer 
                 .click('nextButton');
           })                                       
          .waitForElementVisible('.element5',1000,false,function(){
           client.click('.element5');  //This would select the fifth answer 
           }) 
}
```

Detailed explanation:
http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#waitForElementVisible

**Usage:**

```
do{
    test(client);
    client.click('submit_or_whatevertothenextpage');
}while (client.except.to.not.be.visible(".result_element_non_existing"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  But i do need a loop because the questions and answers are generated randomly so I might get the same type of answer over and over again. With your code, once is found then it would finish.

Comment: Updated the answer but kind of stupid way to do it, because you didn't describe the behaviours after each test ,so just converted the code above into method and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved my problem with the code below.

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
>
>   //If answer type is yes/no, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.yesAnswer.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@yesAnswer').to.be.visible.after(5000);
>         preTestPage.click('@yesAnswer');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If answer type is text input, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.textInputAnswer.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.setValue('@textInputAnswer',10);
>         preTestPage.api.keys(client.Keys.ENTER);
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If answer type is multiple choise with submit button, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.submitAnswerButton.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@firstSubmitAnswer').to.be.visible.after(5000);
>         preTestPage.click('@firstSubmitAnswer');
>         client.pause(1500);
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@submitAnswerButton').to.be.enabled.after(5000);
>
>         preTestPage.click('@submitAnswerButton');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If answer type is multiple answer, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.firstMultipleAnswer.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.click('@firstMultipleAnswer');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If none of the above then is the end of the test so do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.wellDoneButton.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>         // Element is visible, do the appropriate tests
>
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@wellDoneButton').to.be.visible.after(5000);
>         preTestPage.click('@wellDoneButton');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(1000);
>         i = false;
>         console.log("i = " + i + "contador = " + contador);
>         return;
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   }
>
>
> }   },
> ```

Now the problem is, the for loop is not really ideal because im not sure how many questions there are in total and it seems that nightwatch js (or node.js im not sure) continue running all the iterations in my loop even if i put a break when the last screen is presented.  So my test hangs and stay there until the for loop finishes in the background checking all the answers up to the number of iterations i setup.

Somebody suggested to use a while(true), however now the problem is that for some reason node.js hangs and it seems im doing an infinite loop here so it completely crashes.   I suspect my break; command is not doing anything here.  What am i doing wrong here?

> ```
> var i = true;
> var count = 0;
> while (i) {
>
>   //If answer type is yes/no, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.yesAnswer.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@yesAnswer').to.be.visible.after(5000);
>         preTestPage.click('@yesAnswer');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If answer type is text input, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.textInputAnswer.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.setValue('@textInputAnswer',10);
>         preTestPage.api.keys(client.Keys.ENTER);
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If answer type is multiple choise with submit button, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.submitAnswerButton.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@firstSubmitAnswer').to.be.visible.after(5000);
>         preTestPage.click('@firstSubmitAnswer');
>         client.pause(1500);
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@submitAnswerButton').to.be.enabled.after(5000);
>
>         preTestPage.click('@submitAnswerButton');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If answer type is multiple answer, do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.firstMultipleAnswer.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>
>         preTestPage.click('@firstMultipleAnswer');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(2000);
>
>     } 
>   });
>
>   //If none of the above then is the end of the test so do this
>   preTestPage.api.element('css selector', preTestPage.elements.wellDoneButton.selector, function (result) {
>
>     if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
>         // Element is visible, do the appropriate tests
>
>         preTestPage.expect.element('@wellDoneButton').to.be.visible.after(5000);
>         preTestPage.click('@wellDoneButton');
>         preTestPage.api.pause(1000);
>         i = false;
>         console.log("i = " + i + "count = " + count);
>         return;
>
>     } 
>   });
>   count++;
>
>   }
> ```